# I need to parse 250 files, totalling at 1gb of data and upload it to a SQL server. Can I get more efficient than this?

Tags: c#, sql, file, parsing

My current method takes ~40 minutes to parse all of this data :

Current logic is:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    using (var input = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        while (!input.EndOfStream)
        {
            City parsedCity = ParseCity(input.ReadLine());
        }
        SQL.submit()
    }
}
```

You may assume the parsing is the quickest possible.

Comment: What is the format of the file? May be you could directly load it to SQL server

Comment: Well, which part is taking the time?

Comment: Do you have to do it every day (hour)? Ten minutes seem to be reasonable.

Comment: The only faster way would be to use multiple threads.  If its always 250 files you could seperate that into 5 different threads.  Each thread in theory would submit 50 files one after another.  This would only be "faster" if you have a CPU that can run 5 threads.

Comment: @AakashM - If I were to guess.  The uploading part.  10 minutes for 1GB seems reasonable.

Comment: It depends.  What does `SQL.submit()` do?

Comment: If you only have to do this as a one-off import, then it doesn't really matter. Perhaps if it's recurring...

Comment: @RamHound..any CPU can run five threads with windows installed. Concurrently if multicore, time spliced otherwise. Still potential performance gain on single core if bottleneck is IO

Comment: If it works ok, 10 min is not a big deal. *Go for coffee and you're done

Comment: The function that is doing the most work is:
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(valuetype System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode)
So my guess is that submitting to the database is the bottleneck.
Would then, it be better to Submit after each file instead of all at once in the end?
Taking into use what others have recommended about parallelism, I could then Submit after each thread comes back from parsing say 10 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  Experiment with the maxParallelism, start with the number of cores in your system:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var maxParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxParallelism }, ParseAndPersist);
    }

    public static void ParseAndPersist(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        //Load entire file

        //Parse file

        //Execute SQL asynchronously..the goal being to achieve maximum file throughput aside from any SQL execution latency

    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible! Two things I noticed: 1. SQL Submits take SUPER LONG. 2. If I don't submit until all the fiels are parsed, I run out of memory, and crash! ( on a machine with 12gb :O ) So there must be an in-between. I will try polling the amount of memory my program is using and force submit when it hits this barrier.

Answer (score 1):

you could try parsing the files [in parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) rather than sequentially.  You could also try only submitting the sql after parsing all files.

Whether these make any difference its hard to say, as you don't give much information about what your sql submit is doing, but I'd have thought that processing the files in parallel would definitely be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Going by what you said, each file roughly about 4MB which is not too big to read the whole file into memory and perform the parsing once/per line if you have to navigate through the string buffer in memory. You can also leverage Parallel tasks to process multiple files in parallel - taking advantage of your multicores processor.

Comment: yeah reading the whole file in in one go is a decent idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your bottleneck is actually the SQL queries/inserts.  Are you sure the problem is parsing the file[s]?  If it's SQL, I would suggest caching what you have and then doing a bulk data copy.

Comment: I would also suggest the same. I am guessing that the part of the operation that slows down the whole operation would be the SQL.Submit() statement. An alternate approach to this would be to read the files convert them into a Delimited file and use sql server's Bulk Insert operation to read all rows into a temp table at one go. In my experience when a huge dataset is involved hitting the database 1 time with a dataset of n rows is much faster than hitting the database n times.